Warnings and performance issues on RoomPlan Application on first run
When I run the application on my device, the camera view with the RoomPlanView scan is loading slow on the first run of the application.
Steps to reproduce:

Download the RoomPlan example app offered by Apple on their official RoomPlan Documentation website here.
Run the application from Xcode on physical device that has LiDAR. (in my case I run it on iPhone 12 Pro Max with iOS 17.5.1, my Xcode version is Version 15.4 (15F31d))
On the installed app, tap on "Start Scanning" button.
Watch the console for warnings.

The warnings for me are the following:
Could not locate file 'default-binaryarchive.metallib' in bundle.
fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
Errors found! Invalidating cache...
fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
Errors found! Invalidating cache...
Class for component AccessibilityComponent already registered
Registering library (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreRE.framework/default.metallib) that already exists in shader manager. Library will be overwritten.
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/suFeatheringCreateMergedOcclusionMask.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arKitPassthrough.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/drPostAndComposition.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arSegmentationComposite.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute0.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute1.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute2.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute3.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute4.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute5.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute6.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute7.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Json Parse Error line 18: Json Deserialization; unknown member 'EnableARProbes' - skipping.
Json Parse Error line 20: Json Deserialization; unknown member 'EnableGuidedFilterOcclusion' - skipping.
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/suFeatheringCreateMergedOcclusionMask.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arKitPassthrough.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/drPostAndComposition.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arSegmentationComposite.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute0.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute1.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute2.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute3.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute4.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute5.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute6.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute7.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
Registering library (memorylib_12950169728) that already exists in shader manager. Library will be overwritten.
Registering library (memorylib_12950169728) that already exists in shader manager. Library will be overwritten.
Registering library (memorylib_12950169728) that already exists in shader manager. Library will be overwritten.
Registering library (memorylib_12950169728) that already exists in shader manager. Library will be overwritten.
Registering library (memorylib_12950169728) that already exists in shader manager. Library will be overwritten.
Registering library (memorylib_12950169728) that already exists in shader manager. Library will be overwritten.
Registering library (memorylib_12950169728) that already exists in shader manager. Library will be overwritten.
Registering library (memorylib_12950169728) that already exists in shader manager. Library will be overwritten.
Registering library (memorylib_12950169728) that already exists in shader manager. Library will be overwritten.
<0x103f207a0> Gesture: System gesture gate timed out.
<<<< FigCaptureSourceRemote >>>> Fig assert: "err == 0 " at bail (FigCaptureSourceRemote.m:275) - (err=-12784)
<<<< FigCaptureSourceRemote >>>> Fig assert: "err == 0 " at bail (FigCaptureSourceRemote.m:511) - (err=-12784)
<<<< FigCaptureSourceRemote >>>> Fig assert: "err == 0 " at bail (FigCaptureSourceRemote.m:275) - (err=-12784)
<<<< FigCaptureSourceRemote >>>> Fig assert: "err == 0 " at bail (FigCaptureSourceRemote.m:511) - (err=-12784)
<<<< FigCaptureSourceRemote >>>> Fig assert: "err == 0 " at bail (FigCaptureSourceRemote.m:275) - (err=-12784)
<<<< FigCaptureSourceRemote >>>> Fig assert: "err == 0 " at bail (FigCaptureSourceRemote.m:511) - (err=-12784)
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
<<<< AVPointCloudData >>>> Fig assert: "_dataBuffer" at bail (AVPointCloudData.m:217) - (err=0)
<<<< AVPointCloudData >>>> Fig assert: "_dataBuffer" at bail (AVPointCloudData.m:217) - (err=0)
<<<< AVPointCloudData >>>> Fig assert: "_dataBuffer" at bail (AVPointCloudData.m:217) - (err=0)
<<<< AVPointCloudData >>>> Fig assert: "_dataBuffer" at bail (AVPointCloudData.m:217) - (err=0)
<<<< AVPointCloudData >>>> Fig assert: "_dataBuffer" at bail (AVPointCloudData.m:217) - (err=0)
<<<< AVPointCloudData >>>> Fig assert: "_dataBuffer" at bail (AVPointCloudData.m:217) - (err=0)
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
generating texture with resolution of 1286, 1286
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header
Failed initializing ADJasperPointCloud from memory: contains invalid header

When the warning appears in the console, the app does not load instantly the camera view with the RoomPlan. It has a delay of a couple of seconds.
This only happens once at first run.
Does anyone managed to fix this issue in order to run smoothly from the beginning, or have any ideas?
Note: I noticed that it doesn't affect if the app has SwfitUI in it or not. The example from apple uses only UIKit, and I also encountered the same behavior on Kodeco's RoomPlan example that uses SwfitUI.

I have experienced the same thing, the way I have currently solved it is to just load a roomplan view when my app is launching to "warm it up". This puts the delay on the start of the app where it is less noticeable to the user. Not ideal, but does make it snappy when showing the roomplan view in my app.
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //...
    //Warm up roomplan
    if AppDelegate.isLiDARAvailable() {
        let _ = RoomCaptureView(frame: window.frame)
    }
}

